# Uncertainty of transistor hfe/beta values

Tags: transistors

When we buy transistors of the same type, what is the typical uncertainty of hfe and beta of the transistor? For example, if I bought two BC212B transistors in the shop, when I measure hfe, I would get 221 and 176. These numbers are quite far away from each other. What is the typical difference between these values, 5% or 10% or how much?

Comment: Note that this involves the "for dummies" explanation where BJT transistors are current-amplifiers and not transconductance elements. Analog designers know better. "Art of Electronics" AOE is the classic textbook which battles "hfe-think" and instead tells the truth. Transistors are based on Ebers-Moll equation, where the EB potential-hill is controlling the Ie emitter current.  So, if we regard the Ib base current as just an unwanted leakage, then we can design our circuitry properly, so that variable hfe is irrelevant. Otherwise, we might need trimpots and thermistors in every BJT stage.

Comment: This is why good circuits don't deoend up on exact values of beta

Comment: They are vary enough you can't use the value for design purposes other than to assume that "they are very large" which allows the gain terms in your negative feedback equations to approximate themselves out of the equations.

Comment: If one absolutely needs it, you can buy matched pair transistors. But one rarely needs it in most circuits.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have any guarantees.

The range is specified in the data sheet.

For Omsemi BC212B, the maximum is not even given. Only typical and minimum, for certain bias conditions, so the same transistor will have different current gain, depending on the currents.

Which is why any circuit that depends on the *h*<sub>FE</sub> being near some value are quite bad and they should be designed so that a wide range for *h*<sub>FE</sub> is allowed.

Comment: To be fair, one *can* order transistors with binned hFE - if doing so is justified by a good reason (usually it's not...) Even then the binned range is quite large.

Answer (score 8):

Bipolar transistor *h*<sub>FE</sub> varies a lot with temperature and collector current. It also falls off at high current and low V<sub>CE</sub> (quasi saturation conditions). For example, here's a [PN2222](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf):

[image]

Here are a lot of other transistors measured by [an experimenter](https://www.biophysicslab.com/2021/04/27/testing_transistor_hfe/):

[image]

In addition, at the same operating point, *h*<sub>FE</sub> varies quite a lot between two individual transistors having the same part number.

So, basically, check the datasheet minimum and maximum values. Note they are specified for a certain I<sub>C</sub> (or I<sub>C</sub> range), V<sub>CE</sub>, and temperature, so the above variations still apply.

It's generally a bad idea to rely on a known value of *h*<sub>FE</sub> in a circuit. The circuit designer's job is to make sure it works across the range of possible *h*<sub>FE</sub>.

If you need two transistors to have the same *h*<sub>FE</sub>, for example, to get matched input bias current in the input stage of a discrete opamp, then that's another question. If you buy matched transistors, that is a component with two transistors inside, and the manufacturer went to the trouble of matching them, then... you'll still get a wide range of *h*<sub>FE</sub>, but you also get a maximum *h*<sub>FE</sub> mismatch between the two transistors.

For example [BCM847](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/BCM847BS.pdf) gives you about +/-10% *h*<sub>FE</sub> mismatch between the two transistors, and +/-2 mV V<sub>BE</sub> mismatch. Much better than two random transistors, and it's pretty cheap. However the two transistors are independent chips, so their temperature won't track: if one heats up more than the other, no more matching.

One step up is monolithic matched transistors like [SSM2212](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2261092.pdf). They're on the same chip, so they have excellent *h*<sub>FE</sub> and V<sub>BE</sub> match, and temperature will track. But it is quite expensive.

Answer (score 6):

I just pulled (11) PNP 2N4403 (any small signal BJT that isn't in a TO-39/TO-205AD package, or better, is *beneath my notice*) from one 1000-bag laying about. Using a base current set to \$10.0\:\mu\text{A}\$ for each, I found the following \$\beta\$ values: 236, 170, 176, 177, 200, 176, 176, 196, 184, 260, and 180. Most are hugging close to 170-180, but two of them were significantly higher.

[Central Semi](https://my.centralsemi.com/datasheets/LSSGP063.PDF) shows this range:

[image]

There is quite a range listed for the device. This wide range is ***typical***. Not abnormal.

If minimum and maximum values are stated then combine them like this, \$\sqrt{100\,\cdot\,300}\approx 173\$. That will often get close to a typical value. *(As it did here, it seems.)* But as can be seen, the spread around that value is also quite wide.

Answer (score 5):

*h*<sub>FE</sub> will be somewhere between the minimum and maximum specified in the data sheet under the specified bias and temperature conditions.
That is about all you can really say.

Moving away from those conditions, it will drop like the side of a house as you approach saturation, and a good rule of thumb is that well fully saturated, the *h*<sub>FE</sub> is about 10, but it will also drop at high current (the so-called beta droop).

The usual practice is to try to design so that any *h*<sub>FE</sub> greater than a specified minimum will work, because matching transistors for *h*<sub>FE</sub> and V<sub>BE</sub> is a pain in the arse (you sometimes need to, but feedback really is your friend).

Answer (score 3):

Many transistors are available with binned hFE so you can purchase transistors with a guaranteed range: (this is from the BC547 Fairchild [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf))

[image]

As you can see, the range is only about 2:1 from highest to lowest in that range. So if you purchase a BC547B the hFE will be betwee 200~450 guaranteed (under the specified test conditions only, of course and you can *infer* the range of hFE under other conditions since the variations with current and temperature tend to be similar).

If you are using the transistor as a switch you can simply design for the lowest possible hFE.

Answer (score 1):

> when I measure hfe, I would get 221 and 176. These numbers are quite far away from each other.

1. There's no single hfe value even for a single transistor. Values given in the datasheet, or measured by you using a "clever" multimeter, are not necessarily useful for much beyond a ballpark. hfe depends on temperature, collector current and collector-emitter voltage. All of those have to be representative of the ranges the transistor encounters in your circuit, and then you'll get ranges of hfe, instead of a single value.
2. Usually you'd want to design so that the hfe doesn't figure much into the performance of the circuit. A more important parameter may be offset voltage, e.g. when you're putting together differential pairs.

   There are BJT building block circuits targeted for use with lateral transistors you can get in a CMOS process. Those transistors have a wide spread of hfe, and their gain is rather low, in the 20-50 range. If you assemble such a circuit using the "quite far away" transistors you think are "bad", it will have excellent performance!
3. Don't use hfe as an explicit current gain in the circuit, i.e. don't treat it like it was a resistance value on a resistor. It's not. To get a certain current gain, you'll want to use one or more transistors set up in a current amplifier setup, with feedback to stabilize this gain.

Anecdote: There are many discrete analog transistor circuits that I've designed and evaluated on the breadboard where if you asked me what the hfe of each transistor was, I wouldn't be able to tell you other than a rather wide ballpark ("100-300 is my guess"). The whole point was that it shouldn't matter all that much. In some specific applications it will matter, but even then you should perform measurements in the same configuration as in the application circuit. And then usually you don't care for hfe match, but just guaranteeing a certain minimum hfe value needed for the circuit to perform adequately. Usually (exceptions apply) the higher the hfe, the better, i.e. out of a bunch of transistors of a given type, it's not a problem when their gain is on the "high end".

**Corollary:** Be very suspicious if you start looking for "close together" hfe values. You may have a problem with your design, not with the transistor you use.